# Aggregate may not appear in WHERE clause even if i dont have condition while using SUM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I  have this below query

```
SELECT A.*,SUM(ISNULL(B.DEPTRAN_DEPOSIT,0)-ISNULL(B.DEPTRAN_WITHDRAWAL,0)) as BALANCE
 FROM DEPOSITFDMASTER  A
INNER JOIN DEPOSITTRANSACTION B ON A.DEPSUBTYPE_ID=B.DEPSUBTYPE_ID AND A.FD_ID=B.DEPOSIT_DATAID WHERE SUM(ISNULL(B.DEPTRAN_DEPOSIT,0)-ISNULL(B.DEPTRAN_WITHDRAWAL,0))>10
```

when i try to execute i will get the below error. If i remove where condtion then the query will work properly.

```
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.
```

P.S:`DEPTRAN_DEPOSIT` and `DEPTRAN_WITHDRAWAL` both having DataType `Decimal(18,2)`.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Use `HAVING` instead.

Comment: You can't use `SUM` in `WHERE`. you need to either group by all columns of A and use having, or use `SUM` with an `OVER` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use GROUP BY and HAVING. Something like this

```
SELECT 
    A.*
    ,SUM(ISNULL(B.DEPTRAN_DEPOSIT,0)-ISNULL(B.DEPTRAN_WITHDRAWAL,0)) as BALANCE
FROM DEPOSITFDMASTER  A
INNER JOIN DEPOSITTRANSACTION B 
ON 
A.DEPSUBTYPE_ID=B.DEPSUBTYPE_ID 
AND     
A.FD_ID=B.DEPOSIT_DATAID 
GROUP BY [All columns in A] --like that A.Column1,A.COlumn2,....,A.ColumnN
HAVING SUM(ISNULL(B.DEPTRAN_DEPOSIT,0)-ISNULL(B.DEPTRAN_WITHDRAWAL,0))>10
```